# World of goo is not in Ubuntu Software Centre?

Tags: 11.10, software-center

I bought world of goo about 1 year ago and I wanted to install it again on Oneiric Ocelot but it seems that it's not available anymore.

So, can someone confirm this? If it's not there, shouldn't I be able to install something I paid for?

Thank you

Comment: It came back now. Are you having the same problem @Tofi ?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I still do not have it listed in the Software Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite adding all sources I still could not find it via normal searching.  However I did find it by going to File -> Reinstall previous purchases... in the Software Centre.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the sources of software available, even the Partner.
You can do that with Synaptic, but you need yo install it. Or in the Update Manager, clicking below in Configuration.